# Assign-and-compare in go's while-equivalent?

Tags: go

In Go you can do:

```
if foo := bar() ; foo != nil {
    ...
}
```

In C/C++ you can do:

```
while ((foo = bar()) != NULL) {
    ...
}
```

However, Go's syntax does not seem to provide any equivalent way of doing assign-and-compare in a while loop; Go has replaced `while` with a specific invocation of `for` (e.g. `for a` is equivalent to `for ; a ;`).  Simply trying to use the `if` version syntax confuses the parser, as it's expecting there to be a third statement.

I could just say:

```
for foo := bar() ; foo != nil ; foo = bar() {
    ....
}
```

but in this case, the `bar()` call is fairly long, complex, and not easy to break out into its own function (although I could do something like declaring a local `func` to call, but that still reduces the clarity of the code).

For now I am doing:

```
for {
    foo := bar();
    if foo == nil { break; }
    ...
}
```

but this seems unclean, both because it separates the loop criteria from the loop statement itself, and because it relies on `break`.

So, is there a clean, idiomatic way of doing an assign-and-compare in a while loop in Go?  This is such a common use case I can't imagine that there's no way of doing it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.  Go has no while statement, only the special form of the for statement - and assignment is a statement, not an expression. Your examples are IMHO idiomatic Go.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an iterator, similar to [bufio#Scanner.Scan](//golang.org/pkg/bufio#Scanner.Scan):

```
package main

type bar struct { foo int }

func (b *bar) next() bool {
   b.foo++
   return b.foo < 10
}

func main() {
   var b bar
   for b.next() {
      println(b.foo)
   }
}
```

Then in the `Next` function, you can put all the complicated logic you need.

Comment: It seems that this is just an even more complicated form of the `for foo := bar(); foo; foo := bar()` approach that wasn't feasible at the time either (in that `bar()` specifically couldn't be broken out into its own function).